# Healpy pix2ang: Convert from HEALPix index to RA,Dec or glong,glat

Tags: python-2.7, astronomy, healpy

I am new to HEALPix and fairly new to Python as well. I try to use healpy to convert a HEALPix index to RA,Dec.
I get that I have to use pix2ang, but cannot figure how to convert the output theta,phi into RA,Dec... I tried this:

```
import healpy as hp
import numpy as np
theta, phi = hp.pix2ang(256, 632668    ,nest=True) 
ra= phi*180./np.pi
dec = 90.-(theta*180./np.pi)
```

but it does not seem to give the correct result.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 4):

First of all the method `pix2ang(nside,indx)` gives you the coordinates of pixel with number indx. The pixel number is not directly related to a coordinate, i.e. two consecutive pixel numbers are not necessarily next to each other.

Second, as written in the manual of Healpix (which is the underlying code for healpy) (http://healpix.sourceforge.net/html/csubnode2.htm) the angle theta is defined in range [0,pi] and therefore it cannot directly represent declination [-pi/2,pi/2].

So what I do is I define a transformation and I implement it in two functions, for instance:

```
def IndexToDeclRa(index):
    theta,phi=hp.pixelfunc.pix2ang(NSIDE,index)
    return -np.degrees(theta-pi/2.),np.degrees(pi*2.-phi)

def DeclRaToIndex(decl,RA):
    return hp.pixelfunc.ang2pix(NSIDE,np.radians(-decl+90.),np.radians(360.-RA))
```

then the map itself will not be in Decl&RA but if you stick to using `IndexToDeclRa` and `DeclRaToIndex` you'll effecively have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the example below, from [here](https://emfollow.docs.ligo.org/userguide/tutorial/skymaps.html).

```
ipix = 123
theta, phi = hp.pix2ang(nside, ipix)
ra = np.rad2deg(phi)
dec = np.rad2deg(0.5 * np.pi - theta)
```